# How to Convert SQL Query to Rails Active Record Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Query statement

```
select * from timetables where user_id IN
   (SELECT user_id FROM timetables GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

I don't want to use find_by_sql.
because find_by_sql returns array.

I want like to use a mixture of (.where, .group, .having...)

help me...

Comment: What do you expect the query to return if not an array ≡ rowset?

Comment: sorry.. I don't understand your question.. I need Active Record : relation ...

Comment: rails api say 

where returns a new relation,
find_bysql returns a array. I need active record relation

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that the result of subquery would be interpreted by ruby, not by MySQL, drastically slowing down the performance, but here you go:

```
Timetable.where(user_id: Timetable.group(:user_id)
                                  .having('count(*) > 1')
                                  .pluck(:user_id))
#⇒ Timetable::FriendlyIdActiveRecordRelation < ActiveRecord::Relation
```